# Using a class defined in App_Code in web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I have a class named `CustomWebAuditEvent` defined in `App_Code/CustomWebAuditEvent.vb` and I'm trying to use it in a eventMappings of my `Web.Config`

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
  <eventMappings>
    <clear />
    <add name="HandeledException"
         type="CustomWebAuditEvent"
     />
  </eventMappings>
....
```

I got the error message:

> Could not load type 'CustomWebAuditEvent'

So I tried

- `type="CustomWebAuditEvent, App_Code"`
- `type="CustomWebAuditEvent, App_Code.CustomWebAuditEvent"`
- `type="CustomWebAuditEvent, __Code"`
- `type="CustomWebAuditEvent, __Code.CustomWebAuditEvent"`

and all I got is this error message :

> Could not load file or assembly 'App_Code' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

How could I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried appending your Assembly Name before App_Code?

Comment: Have you defined a namespace in the `.vb` file?

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed Since it's in the `App_Code` folder of my Web application, I thought there is no Assembly Name, Right?

Comment: @Oded No Namespace, but I also tried to add one without success.

Comment: There is an assembly name - it just gets compiled automatically and behind the scenes. It would have the website namespace dot class name.

Comment: @Oded my mistake, it's a `ASP.NET 3.5 Website`, not a  `Web Application`

Comment: Obvious question, but is CustomWebAuditEvent `public` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my CustomWebAuditEvent class into a separated class library and put the compiled assembly in my bin folder.

Note: I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484237/cannot-reference-custom-event-from-web-config) that describe the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `CustomWebAuditEvent` out of `App_code` and just placing the class in the same directory as `web.config`. Then in `web.config`, reference it as `ClassName.CustomWebAuditEvent`

I have seen this happen before, although I don't know what causes App_Code to not be recognized.